# How to style specific links in a footer?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style only 2 links in a footer and can't figure out how to do that in css.

[This is the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsqu8.png)

[And the CSS I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aZ2l.png)

I'm having some trouble posting direct code so I screenshotted both the CSS and HTML

Answer (score 2):

CSS should be, note no spaces before "navbar-default" and "orange"

```css
footer.navbar-default li.orange {
    color: #c5ae51;
}
```

But better to drop `footer` and `li` selectors:

```css
.navbar-default .orange {
    color: #c5ae51;
}
```

Comment: Dropping `footer` and `li` might not be a good idea. Just saying!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your complete code so that I figured it out.

try, this should work for you.

```
.navbar-default li.orange {
    color: #c5ae51;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To add css a instead of li see below

```
footer.navbar-default li.orange a{
color: #c5ae51;
```

}